# Why we are using Jms Serializer in Symfony

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I have Used FosRestBundle in my project.In the Documentation they used the JmsSerializer.I want know how it could be used.

Comment: Make a research - that's how people get knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Check out the JMS Serializer documentation at http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer

From the introduction:

> This library allows you to (de-)serialize data of any complexity.
> Currently, it supports XML, JSON, and YAML.
>
> It also provides you with a rich tool-set to adapt the output to your
> specific needs.
>
> Built-in features include:
>
> - (De-)serialize data of any complexity; circular references are handled gracefully.
> - Supports many built-in PHP types (such as dates)
> - Integrates with Doctrine ORM, et. al.
> - Supports versioning, e.g. for APIs
> - Configurable via PHP, XML, YAML, or Doctrine Annotations